# React InstantSearch: RefinementList filters overrides Configure filters

Tags: react-instantsearch, typesense

## Question

How can I apply custom search filters in a way that is compatible with the filters being applied by the `RefinementList`?

## Background

I am trying to design search functionality where users can search in two ways:

1. The "normal" way of searching for a given string to appear anywhere in any search document
2. A specific lookup of a given set if IDs. Users would expect the search result to be all of the search documents that contain any of the IDs given. No more, no less.

I switch from search option one to option two when I detect that the search input contains only IDs in a valid format

## Current Implementation

I have found that the easiest way to get my search engine (typesense) to return results for search option two is to only use the `filter_by` option with an asterisk search, like so:

```json
{
    "query_by":"product_number,ean_number",
    "collection":"products",
    "q":"*",
    "filter_by": "product_number:=[123, 456]"
}
```

Which will return any search document with `product_number` 123 or 456.

So, in my custom `SearchBox` component I call `refine('*')` and set the filters in the `Configure` component when I detect that the search should follow option two.

```js
<InstantSearch>
  <Configure facetFilters={ buildFilterBy(...) } />
  <CustomRefinementList {...} />
</InstantSearch>
```

This works well, but whenever the users selects additional refinements in the `CustomRefinementList`, the `Configure` filters are being overwritten and the search now returns *all* documents that matches the refinements (due to the asterisk search).

Reading around, it seems like I am not supposed to use the `Configure` component to apply filters beyond the initial search/render. I would think there should be a way to apply filters through the `refine` function, though the documentation on what parameters beyond the search string the`refine` function can accept seems a bit lacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Configure` widget, if you use `filters` (instead of `facetFilters` or `numericFilters`), those filters get ANDed to the `facetFilters` that the RefinementList widget adds. This will effectively give you the ability to set a frozen / permanent filter using `Configure`.

You want to make sure you're using v2.4.1 of the typesense-instantsearch-adapter.

More context here: https://github.com/typesense/typesense-instantsearch-adapter/issues/110#issuecomment-1112633962